# LESS combine ruleset into two with different variables

Tags: css, less, right-to-left

I'm trying to combine one ruleset into two different rulesets with variable values swapped. Main purpose is LTR/RTL internationalization.

Usage:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  .directions({
    margin-@{left}: 5px;
  });
}
```

Expected output:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.ltr h1 {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.rtl h1 {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

I was able to get some results with the [Passing Rulesets to Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) function available in Less 1.7

```
.directions(@rules) {
  @left: left;
  .ltr & { @rules(); }
  @left: right;
  .rtl & { @rules(); }
}
```

The problem is that the `@left` variable is always set to the last value used in .directions() mixin (`right` in this case). Is there any way how to swap variable or pass it back outside of the mixin?

Note: I do not want to output LTR/RTL to two separate files, I'm trying to combine them into one file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand Less variables scope and life-time see:

- [Lazy Evaluation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading) (aka Lazy Loading).
- [Variable Semantics](http://earthli.com/news/view_article.php?id=2965)
- [Most Misunderstood](http://getcrunch.co/2015/10/08/less-the-worlds-most-misunderstood-css-pre-processor/)
- [Scope](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope)
- [Last Declaration Wins](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Variables#last-declaration-win---even-after-use)

The solution for your particular case is as simple as:

```
.directions(@styles) {
    .ltr & {
        @left: left;
        @styles();
    }
    .rtl & {
        @left: right;
        @styles();
    }
}
```