# Is it fine to define a variable after it is used in Less and not before?

Tags: html, css, compilation, less, compiler-warnings

So, the question actually is if it is just fine to use:

```
.mytest {
  border:1px solid @black;
}
@black: #000;
```

instead of

```
@black: #000;
.mytest {
  border:1px solid @black;
}
```

I don't see any warnings when I do this and it works fine - the result is

```
.mytest {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

for both cases.

[Demo](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn.mytest%20%7B%5Cn%20%20border%3A1px%20solid%20%40black%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%40black%3A%20%23000%3B%22%7D)

Comment: See the collection of links [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24497347/2712740) for deeper details on what this "lazy-evaluation" thing is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely fine to use it that way because Less does [lazy loading](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading) of variables and so it is not mandatory to declare the variables before they are used. Because of lazy loading, the Less compiler will not throw any errors or warnings for such cases.

As per [Less website](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading):

> Variables are lazy loaded and do not have to be declared before being used.

In fact, I would even go on to say that declaring variables at the end is more beneficial because all the variables are maintained at one place and it leaves no room for some stray declaration accidentally overriding the expected or intended setting.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can as Harry said. And i suggest you to create a file just for storing all your variables definitions and import it. In that way you could have differents themes (files) and configure yout project just replacing one file

Comment: Just in case it was my down vote. It's for very questionable recommendation to store all variables in a separate file. In modern Less there're a lot of different ways to have different themes *w/o* even "replacing one file" (this does not mean that the file-based theming approach is the bad one, but the story is just beyond the scope of the question, hence the downvote).

Comment: No problem, its just an opinion :). Bootstrap framework for example is distributed with a less variables file and for me is very useful to change  aspect of a project just replacing a file (https://bootswatch.com/). It also allows you to send a file to your team graphic designer.