# LESS mixin recursion error to convert pixels to rems

Tags: loops, recursion, less, mixins, less-mixins

I am trying to make a mixin to propery convert pixels to relative ems. I would like it to be flexible enough to allow any property to be used with any number of pixel values.

Any ideas on how to add multiple values to a single property without the recursion error I'm creating inside the for loop?

desired usage example 1:

```
.pixels-to-rems(font-size; 10);
```

desired output:

```
font-size: 10px;
font-size: 1rem;
```

desired usage example 2:

```
.pixels-to-rems(padding; 10,0,20,10);
```

desired output:

```
padding: 10px, 0px, 20px, 10px;
padding: 1rem, 0px, 2rem, 1rem;
```

Here's the mixin as is.

```
@baseFontSize: 10px;
.pixels-to-rems(@property, @pxvals) {
    @pxValue: null;
    @remValue: null;

    .for(@pxvals); .-each(@pxval) {
        @pxValue: @pxValue @pxval;
        @remValue: @remValue (@pxval / @baseFontSize);
    }

    @{property}: ~"@{pxValue}px";
    @{property}: ~"@{remValue}rem";
}
```

.for() mixin found [here](http://is.gd/T8YTOR)

Comment: See [Merge](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature). Obviously since `merge` will concat values into the same property - you'll have to isolate px and rem via some hack (like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/97611099ba7e434626ab) for example).

Comment: As for variable concatenation - no, you can't concatenate variable value "to itself" (Less [variable semantics is different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24497347) - it's not a scripting language). It is still possible to build a list of modified values via loop, but for this specific case the `merge` based implementation is just more simple.

Comment: @Harry, I guess so (I was just thinking that for that kind of use-case I'd rather expect someone to write either Less or CSS plugin to handle it w/o any mixins, as it's not very different from Autoprefixing stuff).

Comment: @seven-phases-max thank you so much for your help!
[Your example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/97611099ba7e434626ab) worked great for the padding usage. However for some reason the 'font-size' usage iterated too many times. Here's the [codepen example](http://codepen.io/lmaharas/pen/wMQeYJ) and compiled output using your code. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's because `.for(number)` call deduces to "call `.-each`  with index value counting from `1` to `number`" thing (i.e. [this](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/generic-for.md#basic-usage)). In your case the easiest way to fix it is just to remove the numeric part of the `.for` code (i.e. everything before `// .for-each`). E.g. like [this](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/NxEgov?editors=0100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Merge](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature) feature. The only trick is that the merge statement will concatenate values into the *same* property rule, thus you'll have to isolate `px` and `rem` rules via some hack. For example like this:

```less
usage {
    .pixels-to-rems(padding, 10 0 20 10);
    .pixels-to-rems(font-size, 50);
}

// impl.:

@base-font-size: 10px;

.pixels-to-rems(@p, @vs) {
    .for(@vs); .-each(@v) {
        @{p}+_:     1px  * @v;
        @{p}@{-}+_: 1rem * @v / @base-font-size;
    }
    @-: ~" ";
}

// .for-each impl. (stripped from the snipped linked in the question)

.for(@array)                 {.for-impl_(length(@array))}
.for-impl_(@i) when (@i > 1) {.for-impl_((@i - 1))}
.for-impl_(@i) when (@i > 0) {.-each(extract(@array, @i))}
```

[Demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cnusage%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.pixels-to-rems(padding%2C%2010%200%2020%2010)%3B%5Cn%20%20.pixels-to-rems(font-size%2C%2050)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20impl.%3A%5Cn%5Cn%40base-font-size%3A%2010px%3B%5Cn%5Cn.pixels-to-rems(%40p%2C%20%40vs)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.for(%40vs)%3B%20.-each(%40v)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40%7Bp%7D%2B_%3A%20%20%20%20%201px%20%20*%20%40v%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40%7Bp%7D%40%7B-%7D%2B_%3A%201rem%20*%20%40v%20%2F%20%40base-font-size%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%40-%3A%20~%5C%22%20%5C%22%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20.for-each%20impl.%5Cn%5Cn.for(%40array)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B.for-impl_(length(%40array))%7D%5Cn.for-impl_(%40i)%20when%20(%40i%20%3E%201)%20%7B.for-impl_((%40i%20-%201))%7D%5Cn.for-impl_(%40i)%20when%20(%40i%20%3E%200)%20%7B.-each(extract(%40array%2C%20%40i))%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: That's nice :) At the very least, we can use this thread for dupe closure even if we don't actually recommend it.

Comment: Thanks so much @seven-phases-max! Worked perfect.