# Rewrite SASS function to LESS

Tags: sass, less

How could you convert this function written in SASS to LESS? It converts pixelvalues to rem.

```
@function unit($number) {
  @return $number / ($number * 0 + 1);
}  

@function getRems($Pixels, $_base-fontsize:16px) {
    $getRems: ();
      @each $pixel in $Pixels {
          $getRems: append($getRems, strip-unit($pixel) / strip-unit($_base-
   fontsize) +    rem,'space');  
   }

  @return  $getRems;
} 

.image {
    padding:getRems(250px 25px 10px 50px);
}
```

Comment: For an ancient solution see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236279. A modern solution would be using [less-plugin-functions](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-functions) and ["vector arithmetic"](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists/blob/master/docs/va.md)

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that