# LESS dynamic variables in nested loops

Tags: loops, nested, less

I'm trying to achieve in LESS loops something in JS or PHP would be really simple. Lets say I have 4 levels to loop. Each level height depends on previous level height. Something like:

```
for (var i; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i = 1) {
        var height = 100 * i;
    } else {
        height = height * 3 - i * 20;
    }
}

assignFinalHeight(height);
```

Is it even possible to achieve in LESS?
Tried guarded mixins something like this:

```
@height: 0;

.count(@lvl) when (@lvl > 1) {
    .for(4); .-each(@lvl) {
         @height: @height * 3 - @lvl * 20;
    }
}

.count(@lvl) when (@lvl = 1) {
    @height: 100 * @lvl;
}

.for(4); .-each(@lvl) {
    .count(@lvl);
    .lvl_@{lvl} {
         height: @height;
    }
}
```

Hope you get the idea.
I also tried some other techniques, but I get errors of recursive variable or  I get generated CSS with first two levels correct and all other levels the same as second one.

Any help is appreciated

---

I'm trying to make something like a playoffs scheme - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiSOy.png. All marked 2 team holders are div's with some css classes. All these holders are wrapped in one div. Like

```
<div>
    <div class="holder lvl_1 pos_1">
        <div class="team_1"></div>
        <div class="other stuff"></div>
        <div class="team_2"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="holder lvl_1 pos_2">...</div>
   <div class="holder lvl_2 pos_1">...</div>
   ...
</div>
```

The only thing left, is the height and positions from top, but these depend on previous level height. Probably I will just make it in JS if it's not possible in LESS :/

Comment: Two things: 1. Less is a declarative language - variables there do not have the semantics of imperative language variables (like JS or PHP) - specifically you can't a construction like `@var: @var ...` (for more details see [these articles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24497347/2712740) for example). 2. I wonder why do you need loop there at all. The final value of the `height` in your pseudocode loop snippet is a constant so the snippet looks sort of weird (or at least redundant) even for JS or PHP.

Comment: In other words, as usual for that ("XY-problem") kind of questions, it's more productive if the question provides more details on *what* you're trying to achieve instead of *how* you think you could make it.

Comment: Added some more info to the question

Comment: So I still can't see why do you need all these variables... Just set `height/top` properties of your specific classes (`.lvl*/.pos*`) directly within the loop.

Comment: But if I change the initial height of the first holder on `lvl_1`, all the `pos_*` and all the `lvl_*` from the second one should change `height` and `top`. I wand this to be valid not just for one design.

Comment: I see. Well, [here we go](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cnlvl_%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%5Ct%40n%3A%205%3B%5Cn%20%20%5Ct%40base-height%3A%20100px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.-%3B%20.-(%40i%3A%201%2C%20%40h%3A%20%40base-height)%20when%20(%40i%20%3C%20%40n)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%40%7Bi%7D%20%7Bheight%3A%20%40h%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.-(%40i%20%2B%201%2C%20%40h%20*%203%20-%20(%40i%20%2B%201)%20*%2020)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D) (a raw example).

Comment: I guess I realized now that what you're missing is just the concept of the [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) (this is actually how loops work in Less). So, in short/general, to reuse a value of an iteration in the next iteration you simply pass this value as parameter to that next iteration (instead of modifying a state of some shared variable - as this simply won't work in most of declarative langs).